# How can you define a Decorator interface in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, interface

I am learning TypeScript and I would like to define an interface for *function decorators*: function that accept a function and return a function.

Here is a snippet that gives the flavor of what I am trying to define:

```
interface IDecoratorFn {
    (fn:function):function
}
```

Can this interface be specified in TypeScript ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there, just need to use `Function` instead of `function`:

```
interface IDecoratorFn {
    (fn: Function): Function;
}
```

You can also define a type alias:

```
type IDecoratorFn = (fn: Function) => Function;
```

Comment: is (fn: Function) => Function the exact same thing as (fn:function):Function ? or is there a difference. Thank you for the answer Nitzan.

Comment: No. `function` isn't a type, it's a js keyword, but you can't use it as a type. `Function` is the base type of all functions, it's the function class/constructor.

Answer (score 0):

typescript has built-in types.

- PropertyDecorator
- ClassDecorator
- MethodDecorator
- ParameterDecorator

In your case, use MethodDecorator as type directly